# Adding a month to last month of the year logic

Tags: sql, oracle

A reporting period is manually entered when a report is running. I've set up the parameters as such:

```
AND (TRUNC(COJ.DATE_ENTERED) >= TO_DATE('&DATE_FROM', 'MM/YYYY') OR '&DATE_FROM' IS NULL)
AND (TRUNC(COJ.DATE_ENTERED) <= TO_DATE('&DATE_TO', 'MM/YYYY') OR '&DATE_TO' IS NULL)
```

These dates  will be entered as 01/2015 and 12/2019 for example. Then returns data between these dates. I need however to add the logic that if its the last month of the year it then adds a month and goes to the next year. Example- 12/2019 would be changed to 01/2020. Can anyone help?

DATE_ENTERED is the data associated with each record. Any questions just ask,

Comment: You can move a date `dt` forward one month with `add_months(dt, 1)`. I think you may need to do this for ALL end-dates, not just for December, though, if the report must INCLUDE the end-month. That is because the `TO_DATE` you wrote will result in midnight on the FIRST day of the month, so your `WHERE` condition will EXCLUDE everything from the last month, except whatever happened exactly at midnight on the first. The correct way is to write `<` (not `<=`) and to use `ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE.....,   1)`.

Comment: What is "it"?  You have two parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean? The two dates are the span in which I want to gather data between. It is just if the month is december i want it to automatically add a month and get the data from Jan the following year instead of Dec.

Comment: Another (minor) comment - if the inputs are strings like '01-2015', with a hyphen, why are you using the format model 'MM/YYYY', with a forward slash, and not a hyphen? Oracle will accept it, but it just doesn't look tidy.

Comment: Which date do you need to add a month to? the from date, the to date or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are entered as `'01/2015'` and `'08/2017'` for example, and **if all the data for August 2017 must be INCLUDED in the report**, then the `where` clause should include

```
...
and (COJ.DATE_ENTERED >= TO_DATE('&DATE_FROM', 'MM/YYYY') OR '&DATE_FROM' IS NULL)
and (COJ.DATE_ENTERED <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('&DATE_TO', 'MM/YYYY'), 1) OR '&DATE_TO' IS NULL)
```

This should be regardless of "December" or whatnot. Also, there is no need to truncate `DATE_ENTERED`.

Comment: They're not seperated with -'s, i updated the question. That was my error. In terms of the add month, i literally ONLY need it to add a month if its December not every month regardless of the day

Comment: @mfgn - OK, I modified the answer accordingly. That is not the big issue though.

Comment: This works but I'm unsure if its adding a month to every month now? or just december?

Comment: @mfgn - I think I said it pretty clearly: it "adds a month" in all cases, and it must do so if you must INCLUDE all the data for the "date-to" month. Don't focus on the code, focus on the business problem. In the example in my Answer, do you need to INCLUDE rows for August 22, for example? The query as you wrote it will EXCLUDE them, and that has nothing to do with August or December.

Comment: @mfgn - actually I think I understand the purpose of `TRUNC` - but then it should be `TRUNC(..., 'MM') - to truncate to the beginning of the MONTH. What you have currently truncates to the beginning of the DAY, which is not helpful. In any case, it is better to write the query the way I did it - it will allow the use of an index on the date column. As soon as you use TRUNC, the index can't be used. (Assuming there is an index to begin with - as there SHOULD be.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem. If you want to add a month to a date, you can use `add_months(date, months)`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Sysdate: ' || sysdate);
    dbms_output.put_line('Sysdate: ' || trunc(sysdate, 'mm'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Sysdate: ' || add_months(sysdate, 12));
    dbms_output.put_line('Sysdate: ' || trunc(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'mm')); 
end;
```

Comment: How would i implement that to my query? Just add what you've wrote in after?

Comment: You can add this function to your query. Example: `select add_months(sysdate, 1) from dual;` But i still don't know what you're trying to do.. Some more code would possibly help.